Inferring Eigenstates of the Original Hamiltonian from the Eigenstates After Exact Diagonalization
I am considering a diagonalization problem encountered in quantum-many body system. As the comment, this is not necessay a exact diagonalization problem but a discrete Fourier problem essentially.
Let's take a spin model as an example. Setting $N = 4$, we have 16 states, namely $|\psi\rangle = |0000\rangle, |0001\rangle, \dots, |1111\rangle$. I can express the Hamiltonian $H$ in the $|\psi\rangle$ representation and diagonalize it. The resulting eigenstates are denoted as $|\tilde{\psi}\rangle$.
To reduce computational cost, we typically implement exact diagonalization by taking advantage of translation symmetry, as follows:
$$
|\phi_j\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{r=0}^{N-1} e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}r} T^r |\psi_r\rangle
$$
where $T^r$ is the translation operator, which acts like $T^1 |0001\rangle = |0010\rangle$. After this encoding, only 6 independent $|\phi_j\rangle$ states remain.
We can now express the Hamiltonian in the $|\phi\rangle$ representation, leading to a $6 \times 6$ matrix. The eigenstates of this matrix are denoted as $|\tilde{\phi}\rangle$.
My question is: since utilizing the translation symmetry eliminates the degeneracy, is it possible to recover the 16 $|\tilde{\psi}\rangle$ from the 6 $|\tilde{\phi}\rangle$, essentially performing a "decoding"? Or due to the loss of information, we can never exactly restore the original 16 $|\tilde{\psi}\rangle$

It should be possible, but I'm really worried about the loss of information. You started with a 16x16 Hamiltonian and later only had a 6x6 matrix, and so I cannot see how this is an exact diagonalisation. Are you sure you are not just supposed to do discrete Fourier transform and diagonalise there? Because it has the nice property of guaranteed existence of inverse transform.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi @Yuqi Qing. Welcome to Phys.SE. Is this from a reference? Which page?

Actually, this question originates from my thoughts while studying quantum-many body exact diagonalization, rather than from a specific paper. As @naturallyInconsistent said, this may be a mathematical question essentially.

It sounds to me like the "original" spin chain has two ends, but then you connect the ends to make a ring (thereby changing the actual model being solved), and diagonalize the ring instead?  Of course you lose all the edge information.  The standard argument is that, for a long enough chain with short enough correlation length, most states in the middle have no idea how the chain ends (or not), so you can mess with the boundary condition and still get a close enough answer.  Key word is close enough.

My bad, I probably misinterpreted the question.  Please ignore my comment above.
Anyway, your formula for $\vert\phi_j\rangle$ seems to be $j$-independent?  And what is $\vert\psi_r\rangle$?

Because there seems to be a mismatch in the language, I will start from the Fourier transformation into the momentum basis and then later argue why there cannot exist any "decoder" and will give a counterexample.
Let's start with the basis set for four particles in the local occupation basis. We can immediately write down all 16 independent states in the following way:
\begin{align}
&| 0000 \rangle &&\to | 0000 \rangle\\
T^r &| 0001 \rangle, ~ r \in \{0,1,2,3\} &&\to | 0001 \rangle, | 0010 \rangle, | 0100 \rangle, | 1000 \rangle\\
T^r &| 0011 \rangle, ~ r \in \{0,1,2,3\} &&\to | 0011 \rangle, | 0110 \rangle, | 1100 \rangle, | 1001 \rangle\\
T^r &| 0101 \rangle, ~ r \in \{0,1\} &&\to | 0101 \rangle, | 1010 \rangle\\
T^r &| 0111 \rangle, ~ r \in \{0,1,2,3\} &&\to | 0111 \rangle, | 1110 \rangle, | 1101 \rangle, | 1011 \rangle\\
& | 1111 \rangle &&\to | 1111 \rangle
\end{align}
where I defined the translation operator implicitly through $T^1 | 0001 \rangle = | 0010 \rangle$. The states on the left are the so-called representative states, because you get all the other states by translating them. (Hence you recover all $1+4+4+2+4+1=16$ states). Notice that some representative states have a different periodicity than others.
Now to get the 16 independent momentum states one takes the Fourier transformation as [I borrowed the notation of these notes]:
\begin{align}
| a(k) \rangle 
= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N_a}}
\sum _{r=0}^{N-1}
e^{−ikr} T^r |a \rangle
\end{align}
where $| a \rangle$ is a representative state and I defined the quasi-momentum $k = m \frac{2\pi}{N}$, $m \in \{0,1, \dots , N-1 \}$. By translational symmetry, states with different momenta are orthogonal and obviously momentum states that are constructed from different representative states $| a \rangle$ are too.

To reduce computational cost, we typically implement exact diagonalization by taking advantage of translation symmetry, as follows:
\begin{align}
| \phi _j \rangle 
= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}
\sum _{r=0}^{N-1}
e^{−i(\frac{2 \pi}{N})r} T^r | \psi _r \rangle
\end{align}
where $T^r$ is the translation operator, which acts like $T^1|0001\rangle=|0010\rangle$. After this encoding, only 6 independent $| \phi _j \rangle$ states remain.

In your definition you only consider the smallest non-zero quasi-momentum $k = 2 \pi/N$, $m=1$. I also count only three states with that momentum and not six. There may be six representative states but only three are non-zero for that momentum. To see this, we can simply compute the momentum state for $k = \pi/4$, $m=1$, using the representative state $| 0101 \rangle $, which has a periodicity of 2:
\begin{align}
\to & \quad
\sum _{r=0}^{3}
e^{−ikr} T^r | 0101 \rangle = | 0101 \rangle + i | 1010 \rangle - | 0101 \rangle - i | 1010 \rangle = 0 .
\end{align}
The only two momenta that are allowed, i.e. give non-zero momentum states, are $k \in \{ 0, \pi \}$ because of the periodicity of 2.

We can now express the Hamiltonian in the $|\phi \rangle$ representation, leading to a 6×6 matrix. The eigenstates of this matrix are denoted as $|\tilde{\phi} \rangle$.

If your Hamiltonian is translational symmetric, your Hamiltonian becomes block-diagonal in the momentum basis. Each momentum is therefore completely decoupled from all the other momenta and this is what is used for exact diagonalization. So indeed we can focus on each momentum individually like $k=0$ and the relevant Hamiltonian reduces in this case to a $6 \times 6$ matrix. Now we can diagonalize this smaller Hamiltonian knowing that it is completely decoupled from the rest of the states.

My question is: since utilizing the translation symmetry eliminates the degeneracy, $\dots$

If we start with $16$ independent states and apply a unitary transformation (like the Fourier transformation) we end up with $16$ independent states, or more generically the same number of degrees of freedom. There is no "degeneracy". If there would be something like "degeneracies", the $16$ states you start with cannot be linear independent from the get go.

$\dots$ is it possible to recover the $16 |\tilde{\psi} \rangle$ from the $6 |\tilde{\phi} \rangle$, essentially performing a "decoding"? Or due to the loss of information, we can never exactly restore the original $16 |\tilde{\psi} \rangle$

In general this is not possible. This would imply that the Hilbert space with its $2^N$ states has a redundancy built in for any Hamiltonian and this is certainly not true. Maybe, there are certain situation where one can use physical intuition for the specific Hamiltonian to understand the structure of eigenstates with different momenta but this falls outside of this question. To conclude, I would like to give a counterexample of an unphysical Hamiltonian where this could never be possible. Let's take $N$ different Hamiltonians ($H_0$, $H_1$, $\dots$, $H_{N-1}$) that are translational symmetric, i.e. are block-diagonal in momentum basis. Then I construct my full Hamiltonian as
\begin{align}
H &= \sum _{m = 0}^{N-1} P_{k=m\frac{2\pi}{N}} H_m P_{k=m\frac{2\pi}{N}} \\ 
&= P_{k=0} H_0 P_{k=0} + P_{k=\frac{2\pi}{N}} H_1 P_{k=\frac{2\pi}{N}} + P_{k=\frac{4\pi}{N}} H_2 P_{k=\frac{4\pi}{N}} + \dots
~ ,
\end{align}
where $P_{k}$ is the projector into a single momentum block with quasi-momentum $k$. In other words, in each momentum block a different Hamiltonian governs the physics. Certainly, you could never reconstruct the full Hamiltonian $H$ by only having information about a single momentum sector. This example might be very artificial but hopefully convinces you that generically this is not possible for an arbitrary Hamiltonian.
I am certain that this is also not possible for "physical" Hamiltonians due to the property of the unitary transformations. (Therefore one could also show this more rigorously). As by my argument from above, this assumes some generic redundancy in the states that make up your Hilbertspace. But this Hilbert space is constructed from the set of all independent degrees of freedoms and thus, the assumption leads to a contradiction.

I truly appreciate your excellent answer! I agree that, in general, we cannot recover the 16 original eigenstates. My concern has now been fully addressed. Thank you and all everyone else once again!
